# Quiero que dependiendo de un input number se genere una cantidad de inputs definido por el usuario

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

El problema que tengo es que no se como hacer para que cuando el usuario baje el valor del input number, se borre uno de los inputs, para que lo cree no tuve problema, pero no se como hacer que al momento de la variable del input baje, uno de los inputs se elimine

```
<input type="number" name="acompaña" class="form-control" id="numero" min=0 max=10 value="<?php echo $_POST['acompaña'] ?? 0 ?>">



---------------------------
var numero = document.getElementById('numero').value;
    var final = 0;
    $('#numero').change(function() {
      var input = document.createElement("input");
      input.type = 'text';
      input.className = 'input';

      var guardar = document.getElementById('pepe');
      var clase = document.querySelectorAll('.input');
      var numero2 = document.getElementById('numero').value;
      for (let i = 1; i <= numero2; i++) {

        if (final > numero2) {
          guardar.removeChild(input);
        } else {
          guardar.appendChild(input);
        }


      }

      final = numero2;
    })
```

Ya estuve probando de varias formas pero no he encontrado la solucion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posibilidad bastante práctica es eliminar todo y volver a crearlo cada vez.

```js
const guardar = $("#pepe");

$('#numero').change(function() {  

  guardar.html("");

  for (let i = 1; i <= +this.value; i++) {
  
    const input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = 'text';
    input.className = 'input';
  
    input.value = i;
  
    guardar.append(input);
    
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="acompaña" class="form-control" id="numero" min=0 max=10 value="1">
<div id="pepe">

</div>
```

Si fuese muy necesario agregar o quitar lo mínimo, se puede calcular la diferencia entre la cantidad de inputs presentes y el valor deseado `let diferencia = $('.input').length - this.value;` si el valor es positivo esa `diferencia` hay que eliminarla, si fuese negativo, esa `diferencia` hay que agregarla. En cualquier caso siempre de itera solo la diferencia. Bueno, al final hice un ejemplo [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/1zgj9otd/1/).

Comment: No soy tan diestro en javascript, tengo una pregunta humilde. Veo que utilizaste jquery para obtener el elemento y crear el `eventListener`, pero utilizaste vanilla js para crear el nuevo `input`. No es preferible, por temas de consistencia, evitar mezclar ambos? Tal vez yo hubiese creado el elemento con jquery. O hubiese obtenido el elemento y creado el listener con vanilla js. Cuál es tu opinión?

Comment: Si @Ariel, yo también prefiero no mezclar.

Comment: @Emeeus a que hace referencia el +this.value? que no entiendo bien eso

Comment: `this` es el elemento que está cambiando, el input en este caso que capturó el evento `change`. `this.value` es el valor de dicho input, y el `+` es para castear ese valor como entero.